# Java:error: Illegal start of expression

Tags: java

There's also an error also which says  error: ';' expected. Here is the code. I checked the format and if I'm missing anything but none. Void is on a class other than the main class.

```
void buy1(){
        System.out.println("Product Code 1: Paracetamol");
        System.out.println("Enter quantity: ");
        quantity = machine1.nextInt();
        price = paracetamol*quantity;
        System.out.println("Price is " +price);
        System.out.println("Enter cash amount: ");
        cash = machine1.nextInt();
        total = cash-price;
        System.out.println("Total: "+total);
    }
```

Up to buy5 then when I run it it says:

```
    drugstore1.java:11: error: illegal start of expression
    void buy1(){
    ^
drugstore1.java:11: error: ';' expected
    void buy1(){
             ^
```

I don't know what is wrong. Help? :(

Here is the whole code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

class Machine {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Machine machine1 = new Machine(System.in);
    int medicine, medicine1, medicine2, medicine3, medicine4, medicine5, amount, change, cash, price, price2, price3, price4, price5, totalquantity, quantity, quantity2, quantity3, quantity4, quantity5, totalamount, total, total2, total3, total4, total5;
    int paracetamol=7, biogesic=6, alaxan=13, neozep=6, amoxicilin=13;
    String answer;   
    void buy1(){
        System.out.println("Product Code 1: Paracetamol");
        System.out.println("Enter quantity: ");
        quantity = machine1.nextInt();
        price = paracetamol*quantity;
        System.out.println("Price is " +price);
        System.out.println("Enter cash amount: ");
        cash = machine1.nextInt();
        total = cash-price;
        System.out.println("Total: "+total);
    }   

    void buy2(){ 
        System.out.println("Product Code 2: Biogesic");
        System.out.println("Enter quantity: ");
        quantity2 = machine1.nextInt();
        price2 = biogesic*quantity2;
        System.out.println("Price is " +price2);
        System.out.println("Enter cash amount: ");
        cash = machine1.nextInt();
        total2 = cash-price2;
        System.out.println("Quantity of purchased items: " +quantity2+  " \nCash amount is " +cash+ "\nTotal amount is " +total2);
    }

    void buy3(){    
        System.out.println("Product Code 3: Alaxan");
        System.out.println("Enter quantity: ");
        quantity3 = machine1.nextInt();
        price3 = alaxan*quantity3;
        System.out.println("Price is " +price3);
        System.out.println("Enter cash amount: ");
        cash = machine1.nextInt();
        total3 = cash-price3;
        System.out.println("Quantity of purchased items: " +quantity3+  " \nCash amount is " +cash+ "\nTotal amount is " +total3);
    }

    void buy4(){
        System.out.println("Product Code 4: Neozep");
        System.out.println("Enter quantity: ");
        quantity4 = machine1.nextInt();
        price4 = neozep*quantity4;
        System.out.println("Price is " +price4);
        System.out.println("Enter cash amount: ");
        cash = machine1.nextInt();
        total4 = cash-price4;
        System.out.println("Quantity of purchased items: " +quantity4+  " \nCash amount is " +cash+ "\nTotal amount is " +total4);
        }

    void buy5(){
        System.out.println("Product Code 5: Amoxicilin");
        System.out.println("Enter quantity: ");
        quantity5 = machine1.nextInt();
        price5 = amoxicilin*quantity5;
        System.out.println("Price is " +price5);
        System.out.println("Enter cash amount: ");
        cash = machine1.nextInt();
        total5 = cash-price5;
        System.out.println("Quantity of purchased items: " +quantity5+  " \nCash amount is " +cash+ "\nTotal amount is " +total5);
    }

        void addproduct(){
        System.out.println("Add product: y/n"); 
        String answer= machine1.nextLine();
    }
}   
public class drugstore1
    {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter Product Code: ");
        medicine = machine1.nextInt();
            if(medicine==1) 
                {
                    machine1.buy1();
                    machine1.addproduct(); 
                } 
            if(medicine==2)
                {
                    machine1.buy2();
                    machine1.addproduct();
                } 
    }while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }

}
```

Comment: the syntax error seems to be somewhere else in the code.

Comment: You certainly tried to write a method within your main method.

Comment: @KevinEsche I have no idea which since it points out there.

Comment: @John like Yassin said, you are defining a method inside a method (`main` in this case), which isn´t possible. Define them at class level.

Answer (score 3):

It is illegal to declare a method within another method.

So instead of the following...

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    public foo(){}
}
```

Do...

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // code
}

public foo(){
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your methods `void buy1(){}` , `void buy2(){}` , `void buy3(){}` .... should be outside of the main

```
class Machine {
   void buy1(){}
   void buy2(){}
   void buy2(){}
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Machine obj = new Machine();

      obj.buy1();
      .....
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that fixed it... but now it has 79 more errors. Can you help me create this program? :(

Comment: Yeah sure, post your errors and lets see what is the problem :)

Comment: Can we talk somewhere? Skype?

Comment: I did what you told me then after it showed 79 errors which are a bunch of cannot find symbol errors. Can you possible try it on your computer? :(

Comment: yes we can talk here, post another question or edit your answer and post your errors so we can find a solution for you.

Comment: Okay. so you see my code... I did what you said and debug it it fixed the only errors that I have earlier and now it has 79 errors which says cannot find symbol on the variables that I declared. Fix?